# Redirect Specific Wildcard Subdomain to a specific URL on another domain

Tags: htaccess

I want to redirect specific wildcard subdomain to a specific URL on another domain. Both domains are on the same server/public_html, and redirect all the inner pages of the wildcard subdomain to the inner pages of the other domain.

For example:

- redirect `music.example.com` to `another.example/music/`

and

- redirect `music.example.com/happy-birthday/` to `another.example/happy-birthday`
- redirect `music.example.com/sing-to-you/` to `another.example/sing-to-you/`

I have more than 100k posts so I cannot make the redirection of the inner pages one by one using `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root using mod_rewrite *before* the WordPress front-controller.

Note that since you have two distinct patterns (root directory to `/music` and everything else to the root directory on the other domain) then you'll need to two rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

# "music.example.com/" to "another.example/music/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^music\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://another.example/music/ [R=302,L]

# "music.example.com/<something>" to "another.example/<something>"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^music\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) https://another.example/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` (condition) directive checks the requested host. The `RewriteRule` naturally redirects to the other domain. In the second rule the URL-path from the request is captured in the `$1` backreference.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent, then change to 301 (ie. `R=301`) but only once you have confirmed that it works OK. 301s can be problematic when testing as they are aggressively cached by the browser.

Comment: Just to add... note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent, then change to 301. Testing with 302 is preferred as it avoids caching issues.